# Refresh device registration with Azure Notification Hub (device SDK)

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I remembered during the Notification Hub preview, we used to call the method `RefreshRegistration` (or something similar, presumably there's different flavour of this on different device SDK), so that the device registration get refreshed in the notification hub, and not automatically removed after 90 days.

In the GA version of Notification Hub devices SDK, I can't find the this method anymore. A few questions I hope experts in the Notification Hub can help:

1. Is the reason behind the missing `RefreshRegistration` method, means that we no longer need to call a different function, instead, we should always call the 'regular' version of registration (e.g. RegisterTemplate/RegisterNavite, etc.) every time?
2. What is the best practice on calling the registration (to Notification Hub) method? Should we make a registration call on every launch of the mobile app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't definitively answer the question about why it was removed, but I can definitely say that the best practice is to re-register for notifications on every launch of the mobile app.

The "Get started" page (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/) recommends putting the registration in this method: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

We've found that this practice works best for our solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! This is what I ended up doing in my app too. In practice, do you ever notice that this had caused too much unneeded registration API calls? Should we do some checking the in the app, say, maybe only call register every other day, or when really needed?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what pricing tier you're using, and how tightly you would like to manage the API usage. We're not in danger of exceeding our limits, so we didn't put in any throttling.

Comment: @P.L. You can register only if the registration doesn't already exist.